# Does this careers posting have the incorrect disclaimer attached?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

The University of Illinois has a careers posting available [here](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/98098/web-programmer-university-of-illinois-at)

At the bottom of the post, though, it has a disclaimer for Marist College:

> About Marist College
>
> Marist College is an independent and comprehensive liberal arts institution located in New York''s historic Hudson River Valley. Situated on 210 acres overlooking the Hudson River, it enrolls 4,787 traditional undergraduate, 799 full and part-time g

This disclaimer has the same text (including the cut off word(s) at the end) as a real [Marist College posting](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/97425/desktop-administrator-marist-college). Did the disclaimer get attached the wrong post?

On a side note: The UofI posting needs more appropriate tags. It looks like someone didn't realize what the tags were for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention, Andy. It does look like a copy and paste error on the part of the recruiter. I'll fix the mistakes and contact the user to clarify how to appropriately use tags.

In the future, when you spot issues on Stack Overflow Career listings, feel free to use the "Flag a problem" feature to notify our team directly.